# Login screen with just a wallpaper and no users

Tags: macbook-pro, login, login-screen

my MacBook Air stopped showing any users on the login screen as well as the buttons in the lower part of the screen. How do I get in?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you unplug the external monitor? Or if you force-reboot with the external monitor unplugged?

Comment: I don’t know, I can’t see because the screen is cracked.

Comment: One guy told me to connect the mouse and the keyboard, then close the laptop and try to wake it up with mouse or keyboard. But as soon as I close the laptop, my external monitor goes into sleep mode and my keyboard which is connected to Orico adapter stops working at all.

Comment: After a reboot (with the external monitor running), you can log in by typing the first character of your user name, pressing enter and entering the password.

Comment: Solved the issue by pressing ⌘ Cmd + F1

Comment: Please post this as an answer below.